# River swimming near Chinon in France's Loire Valley

Tags: france, swimming, rivers, loire-valley

My girlfriend and I are staying just outside Chinon for a week and I am really keen to go for a river bathe/swim, somewhere safe. A bit of a Google suggests Barrou, which is an hour or so away, but I was wondering if there's anywhere a little closer. Normally I could spend some time researching myself, but unfortunately our Internet access is a little intermittent!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This site (in French) shows 11 bathing spots in Touraine on an interactive map.](http://saintpierredescorps-cestouca.blogspot.fr/2010/06/11-sites-pour-se-baigner-et-pique.html?m=1) These include reservoirs (plans d'eau), converted quarries, riverside beaches, as well as lakes. [Here is another interesting page (in French) from the  departmental website, showing swimmable areas in Touraine.](http://www.touraineloirevalley.mobi/rando-velo-canoe/loisirs-de-nature/baignade) Lastly according to [this other website](http://www.ville-data.com/baignade/Chinon-37-37072), the closest swimming location to Chinon is a [riverside beach close to a camping some 11km from the town, commonly known as **Baignade Camping L'Ile-Bouchard**](http://www.gralon.net/tourisme/plages-france/plages-l-ile-bouchard-14602.htm):

> Le lieu de baignade le plus proche de Chinon est la plage BAIGNADE CAMPING située sur la commune de Assay, elle est à 10,7km de Chinon, qualité d'eau de baignade : Très bonne. C'est une plage de bord de rivière.

All in all it makes sense that you'd have to drive a bit to get away from the cities in order for the (river) water to be safe for swimming.

For completeness sake note that you can find more information by typing `baignade rivière chinon` in your favourite search engine.

Comment: Lac de loisir can also be good places for an outdoor swim.

Comment: This one seems not bad : http://www.touraineloirevalley.com/dormir-manger-sortir/activites/parc-de-loisirs-capitaine-bourgueil as it is less than 20 km from Chinon and is free. I couldn't find any significant resources concerning the 'BAIGNADE CAMPING' mentioned by @joernano

Comment: That's some great info, cheers. Internet connection re-established too, so I can check the links! :)

Comment: @audionuma Here's the  relevant information from the linked website: http://www.ville-data.com/plage/baignade-camping/assay/37-1460-37007

Comment: @JoErNanO : what I mean is that your provided link is the only one mentioning this place. No other mentions or website can be found with a search engine or on yellow pages. (although there actually is a 'plan d'eau' there :http://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=assay#map=15/47.0648/0.3085)

Comment: @JoErNanO: Just noticed there are two identical links in your post - was there another link you meant to post, or did you post the same one twice by accident?

Comment: @Ooberdan Thanks for that. Fixed. The mobile app has a tendency to replace links randomly. I should report this one day.

Comment: @JoErNanO - both links still have the same text.

Comment: @Ooberdan Answer body fixed with the right text and the correct link.